# python: how to go "back" a page with splinter

Tags: python, web, splinter

I need to iteratively submit data to a page then re-visit the page:

```
from splinter import Browser

with Browser() as browser:
        # Visit URL
        url = "http://tefam.biochem.vt.edu/tefam/search_seq_form.php"
        browser.visit(url)
```

Instead of repetitively revisiting, how do I simply go "back" to the previous page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Browser back() method:

```
browser.back()
```

This will back to the last visited URL in the history as described in the [API documentation](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/en/latest/api/driver-and-element-api.html).